# multi-project build: execute one task before any project builds

Tags: android, gradle, build

In a multi-project Android build, like

`root
+--- build.gradle
+--- settings.gradle
+--- subproject1
     \--- build.gradle
\--- subproject2 
     \--- build.gradle`

I would like to execute a task that generates code, before any of the projects (`subproject1`,`subproject2`) build. The code generating task is there once for all projects. I would like to put it into the root `build.gradle`. Also in the root `build.gradle`, that all projects (`allprojects`) depend on the code generating task.

```
task code_generating_task << {
  println "I generate code here"
}
preBuild.dependsOn code_generating_task
```

Does not work, because preBuild is not defined in the root `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine to declare a common/transverse task directly in the root project's build script like you did.  In order to create dependencies between each subproject's `preBuild` task and this common `code_generating_task` task you can write the following block in the root project build script:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    subprojects{
        // TODO : add a check on 'preBuild' task existence in this subproject.
        preBuild.dependsOn code_generating_task
    }
}
```